# how to decay array type to const pointer type in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I would like to automatically generate const accessor function for given member but I struggle with arrays. It is possible to "decay" array type to a pointer, but I do not know how to make type of pointed value const? Any obvious method of adding const will only apply the pointer. Of course, I can make specialised accessor for array types, but it is not ideal solution. Returning const pointer to const value would also be acceptable. This is example of incomplete accessor:

```
auto foo() const -> const typename std::decay<decltype(foo_)>::type { return foo_; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to get the address of a member array, simply qualify it as `const`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct fooType {
};

class MyClass {
    public:

    fooType foo_[2];

    auto foo() const -> typename std::decay<const decltype(foo_)>::type
    { return &foo_[0]; }
};

int main() {
    MyClass classObj;
    classObj.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/PjclAf

---

Edit:

The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) states that

> Applies lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer
>   implicit conversions to the type T, **removes cv-qualifiers**, and defines
>   the resulting type as the member typedef type. **This is the type
>   conversion applied to all function arguments when passed by value**.

(emphasis mine)

The important takeaway here is that `std::decay()` always act to "simulate" a pass-by-value mechanism with the type you're feeding it. Cv-qualifiers are dropped iff they can be dropped in a pass-by-value call, **not if they actually define the resulting type**.

Take the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U>
struct decay_equiv : 
    std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, U>::type 
{};

void function1(int happyX) {
    // happyX can be modified, it's just a local variable
    happyX = 42;
    std::cout << happyX << std::endl;
}

void function2(const int *ptrByValue) {
    // ptrByValue can be modified, however its type is 'const int' and that CANNOT be modified
    ptrByValue = (const int*)0xDEADBEEF;
    std::cout << ptrByValue << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << decay_equiv<const int, int>::value << std::endl      // cv-qualifiers are dropped (pass-by-value)
              << decay_equiv<const int[2], int*>::value << std::endl; // cv-qualifiers here CANNOT be dropped, they're part of the type even if passed by value

    const int myConstValue = 55;
    function1(myConstValue);

    const int myArrayToConstValues[2] = {4,2};
    function2(myArrayToConstValues);

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/AW6TJS

In your example you're asking for a constant return value (you can't modify the address of the first element) but asking in the trailing return type for a non-const one, that's why the compiler is complaining and what I just wrote is the reason why the `const` cannot be dropped by `std::decay()`: it is part of the type even in a pass-by-value situation (e.g. `function2()`).

Comment: Wouldn't decay remove const from a type?

Comment: @kpx1894 That's actually a good question. I updated my answer to explain the reasoning behind this.